# React Js Map function not working on a nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to learn ReactJS.
For my projects I am getting data from firestore and then want to display on the screen.

Data in Firestore is stored as :

```yaml
category: "Lemon"
currentUser:
  createdAt: October 21, 2020 at 2:52:25 PM UTC+5:30
  displayName: null
  email: "email@ymail.com"
id: "123"
dish: "vs"
image: "imageurl"
price: "8"
```

To retrieve this data I am using:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let m = [];
  var docRef = firestore.collection("Dish");
  docRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      m.push({
        id: doc.id,
        category: doc.data().category,
      });
    });

    Setmida(m);

    Setmid(false);

    if (mid === false) {
      let big = [];
      mida.map((f) => {
        let items = [];
        var docRef = firestore
          .collection("Dish")
          .where("category", "==", "Lemon");
        docRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            items.push({
              dish: doc.data().dish,
            });
          });
        });

        big.push({
          id: f.id,
          category: f.category,
          items,
        });
      });

      Setdata(big);

      Setload(false);
    }
  });
}, [mid]);
```

Category and Id are well.
But the problem arises when I try to access items.
So far I have tried to access it by index:

```
data[0].items[0]
```

But it just shows `undefined` in console.

When trying to use map on the `data[0].items`. It just doesn't do anything, no errors, it just won't print any details.

Comment: is this a typo: `data[0].items.[0]`? Should it be `data[0].items[0]`? Also, what does `data[0].items` give you?

Comment: yeah that was a typo in question.Fixed it. data[0].items shows the items array : ` Array(0) 0: {dish: "vs"} 1: {dish: "cf"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
  mida.map((f) => {
        let items = [];
        var docRef = firestore
          .collection("Dish")
          .where("category", "==", "Lemon");
        docRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            items.push({
              dish: doc.data().dish,
            });
          });
        });

        big.push({
          id: f.id,
          category: f.category,
          items,
        });
```

`Array.map` runs synchronously, so you are running quickly through all the items in `mida` and kicking off the `docRef.get()` Promises as you go. However, the call to `.map` will run to the end before any of the Promises have completed, so when you try to push `items` in to `big` as the loop is running, the calls to `get` haven't returned and so `items` doesn't yet contain anything.

You could fix this by mapping your Promises in to an array and then using `Promise.all` to wait for them to complete, then calling `Setdata` with the result.

Something like this (untested):

```
 if (mid === false) {
      let big = []
      Promise.all(
        mida.map(f => {
          let items = []
          var docRef = firestore
            .collection('Dish')
            .where('category', '==', 'Lemon')
          return docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              items.push({
                dish: doc.data().dish,
              })
            })
            return { id: f.id, category: f.category, items }
          })
        }),
      ).then(results => {
        Setdata(results)
        Setload(false)
      })
    }
```